# Looking for algorithms that could resolve a combinatorial problem involving a fixed, simple non oriented graph

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics

I am in the research phase of the creation of an algorithm to resolve this problem :

This is sort of an energy minimization problem and I'm looking for inspiration and similar algorithms.

Given a graph that is simple, undirected.
Lets say that each node can have a type defined by an integer.

We are given a quantity of each type at the start, the total quantity is equal to the number of nodes such that in the solution, each node will have a single type.

Each edge in the graph will have a energy value.
This energy value is calculated from a given relationship matrix that tells you the energy value between two types of nodes.

We want to define each node such that the energy total of the edges is minimal.

Example :

Energy matrix :

| - | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 3 |

Graph

A - B - A

Would have an energy total of 2 + 2

while

A - A - B

Would have an energy total of 1 + 2

I have looked in books about algorithms, and this seems like a combinatorial problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem can be reduced to a [(Capacitated) Facility Location problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem), which is considered a [Mixed-Integer Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). There are multiple ways of solving MIP programs, usually, by using a solver such as [SCIP](https://github.com/scipopt/scip), CPLEX, Gurobi, etc.

The total energy served could be thought of as the total demand in Facility Location, the serving variables could be anything, customers, factories, etc.

Modelling the problem constraints requires a heed. Adding them one by one may reduce the complexity of writing them.